# this.props working in console.log of child component, but not rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm passing a recently updated state variable to a child component. In that child component I'm able to `console.log(this.props.response.message)` and see the expected result of the recently updated variable. However, the `this.props.response.message` is not rendering. Do I need to perform some action in a React Lifecycle method? If so, which one and how would that look?

**Parent Component**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import FormSuccess from './FormSuccess';

export default class NewRuleForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super();

    this.state = {
      submitSuccess: false,
      isOpen: false,
      response: {}
    };

    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  
  async handleSubmit(e) {
    let response = await axios.post('localhost:5000',
      {
        data: e.target.id.value
      }
    )
    if (response.data.success) {
      this.setState({
        submitSuccess: true,
        response: response.data
      })

    } else {
      this.setState({
        submitSuccess: false,
      })
    }
   return response
  }
}
render() {
   if (this.state.submitSuccess === true) {
     return <FormSuccess result={this.state.response} />
   }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
      <input type="text" name="id"/>
    </form>
  )
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

**Child Component**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class FormSuccess extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super();
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.props.result.message) // works
    
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Successful Form Submission</h1>
        {/* below doesn't render */}
        <p>{this.props.result.message}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Again, in that child component I am able to `console.log(this.props.response.message)` and see the expected result of the recently updated variable. However, it does not render.

Comment: I don't see how `console.log(this.props.response.message)` can work, since the prop is called "result", not "response"

Comment: it was a typo in the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also you should be careful about data type. If data type is json or something like that, you cant render it but you can write on console.

Comment: The data type was json. Thank you. I refactored the backend server to use `res.send` instead of `res.json` to pass the data from the backend to the front end.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing data in `result` prop,

`<FormSuccess result={this.state.response} />`

You should use it like this,

```
{this.props.result} // Normal case
```

If you are getting object in `result` and want to retrieve `message` from it then use this,

```
{this.props.result.message}
```

Comment: console.log(this.props.result)

Comment: yeah that was my bad, I edited the code for simplicity. I meant to write `this.props.result`. The same issue applies, just a typo in the post.